# How can I print in a box pattern or any sort of pattern?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, printing

What I mean by that is when I print, for example, a Sieve of Eratosthenes, it just prints a long line of numbers vertically with `println()`. With `print()`, it just prints another long line horizontally. I want it so that there's some sort of line you can't go across to.

I attached a snip and for a clearer objective, I drew a red box of where I want the numbers to stop, and where to start.

[image: a snip with a red box]

Comment: Instead of printing immediately, add your numbers to a String. Then whenever the length of your String is acceptable, println it, then empty the String and keep going.

Comment: put condition inside loop when you want to break line use println() there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here is one way. *Suppose you are printing natural numbers from 1 to `n` and you want only **10 natural numbers in a line**, then you can do this:*

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");

    //Add new line if there are 10 elements in a row
    if (i % 10 == 0) System.out.println();
}
```

If you are working with `Sieve of Eratosthenes`, *then the numbers to be printed do not follow a regular sequence*. In that case, you can *count the `number of numbers` printed and add a new line accordingly.*

Suppose you have a `boolean` array `numbers` where if the *index of the array represents a Prime number, then at that index `true` is stored or else `false` is stored.* In that case you may use this:

```java
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (numbers[i]) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        count++;
    }

    if (count == 10) {
        System.out.println();
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

I should add, *if you still want to add more symmetry in your output so that there is proper spacing and the elements appear one below the other*, you can ***replace*** `System.out.print (i + " ")` with
`System.out.print (i + "\t")`.

*The output will appear more beautiful and it will be more readable.*

I hope I have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) for this purpose:

```java
IntStream.rangeClosed(11, 40)
        // print elements in one line
        .peek(i -> System.out.print(i + " "))
        // after every tenth element
        .filter(i -> i % 10 == 0)
        // print new line
        .forEach(i -> System.out.println());
```

Output:

```
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
```